# Is it possible to insert a null value into a column where column data type is a double?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

```
     `enter code here`

                private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                            {
                         GRepository<tblDEIPO_Primary> GR = new GRepository<tblDEIPO_Primary>();
                                    tblDEIPO_Primary objDIE = new tblDEIPO_Primary();
                                    if (txtid.Text == "")
                                    {
                                        objDIE.DIEPONo = txtDIEPO.Text;
                                        objDIE.PoDate = dtpDeiPoDate.Text;
                                        objDIE.Vendor = cmbVendor.Text;
                                        objDIE.Remark = txtRemark.Text;
                                        objDIE.TermsAndConditions = txtTermsAndCondition.Text;
                                        objDIE.TaxType = cmbTaxtype.Text;
                                        objDIE.Tax = Convert.ToDouble(txtTax.Text);
                                        objDIE.TaxAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxAmount.Text);
                                        objDIE.BonusPenalty = s;
                                        if (chkBonus.IsChecked == true)
                                        {
                                            objDIE.BonusPenaltyAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtBonus.Text);
                                        }
                                        else if (chkPenalty.IsChecked == true)
                                        {
                                            objDIE.BonusPenaltyAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtPenalty.Text);
                                        }
                                        objDIE.DeiType = cmbDieType.Text;
                                        objDIE.TypeofInjections = cmbTypeOfInjection.Text;
                                        objDIE.Total =Convert.ToDouble( txtTotal.Text);
                                        objDIE.TotalAmount =Convert.ToDouble(txtAmount.Text);
                                        GR.Insert(objDIE);
                                        GR.Save();}
```

when i click btnSave_Click button that time error ganerate"Input string was not in a correct format."  in   objDIE.Tax = Convert.ToDouble(txtTax.Text);
                    becouse i m insertin blank value in this textbox  ist any solution for that error Plz help.

```
                    > Blockquote
```

Comment: The problem you are having is not in assigning nulls to the database, but rather trying to convert an empty string to a Double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `double.TryParse` to test if the value of your input is a double.

You can replace :

```
objDIE.TaxAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxAmount.Text);
```

by

```
double num;
bool res = double.TryParse(txtTax.Text, out num);
if (res)
{
    // String is a double.
    objDIE.TaxAmount = num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So use `double.TryParse`

```
double taxAmount= 0;
objDIE.TaxAmount = double.TryParse(txtTaxAmount.Text, out taxAmount) ? taxAmount: DbNull.Value;
```